# How to set Set<bean> to ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring, collections

my problem is to set the collection type Set to my user bean.Set is coming from DB with details.

How to set my Set to ObjectMapper class.Please give me some suggetion

**userRole.java**

```
public class UserRole implements Serializable{
    private Integer id;
    private User user;
    private Role role;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }
```

**User.java**

```
public class User implements Serializable{


    private Integer id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
```

**AppService.java**

```
public String getUser(String username) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        System.out.println("dao call");
        User user=new User();
        try{

            user=appDAO.getUser(username);

            System.out.println("the user is "+user);

        }catch(Exception e){

            System.out.println(" Exception is "+e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("user obj.."+user.getUsername());

        User1 user1=new User1();

        user1.setId(user.getId());
        user1.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        user1.setUsername(user.getUsername());
//if i configured like this it is throwing an Excepion in String detailsString line

        user1.setUserRoles(user.getUserRoles());


        String detailsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user1);
        System.out.println("details string is "+detailsString);
            System.out.println("user in String-----"+user1.toString());
    return detailsString;
    }
```

**AuthenticationService.java**

```
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService{
    /*private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthenticationService.class);*/

    @Autowired 
    private AppServiceManager appService;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user=new User();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            String userString = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String userString=appService.getUser(username);

        System.out.println("user string is "+userString);

        try {
            User user2 = mapper.readValue(userString, User.class);

            System.out.println("the user values in authentication serivi "+user2.getPassword());

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Exception is here:**

```
  15:26:23,837 ERROR [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] (default task-4) An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]   15:26:23,837 ERROR [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] (default task-4) An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167) [undertow-servlet-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761) [undertow-core-1.1.8.Final.jar:1.1.8.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.getUser(Unknown Source)
        at com.hello.security.manager.AuthenticationService.loadUserByUsername(AuthenticationService.java:46) [classes:]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        ... 45 more
    Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.hello.security.auditbeans.UserRole["user"]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.User["userRoles"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.UserRole["user"]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.User["userRoles"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.UserRole["user"]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.User["userRoles"]->java.util.HashSet[0]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.UserRole["user"]->com.hello.security.auditbeans.User["userRoles"]-
      15:26:23,837 ERROR [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] (default task-4) An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.: org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:110) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:132) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177) [spring-security-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:211) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar:3.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Comment: can you update your userrole class as well

Comment: i updated UserRole.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by infinite cyclic process when json try serialize from both end of link. [Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288939/410677)

Mark

```
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>(0);
```

Comment: ya i have seen that one but little bit confusion

Comment: where i need to keep @JsonManagedReference and  JsonBackReference

Comment: as i have marked try annotating userRoles field with @JsonManagedReference

Comment: ya i have tried but it giving the same exception... as i have 2 projects like ejb and spring mvc there are two same user classes in both the projects so where can i keep them. and i tried that annotation in ejb side.. still same exception